# Can I know what rewards I have already unlocked

Tags: hearthstone

Is there a way to know what kind of reward giving achievements are already completed on an account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as an achievement tracker or achievement screen in Hearthstone. You have to just use your memory as to which ones you've completed already.

Comment: Blizzard has discussed wanting to track achievements with HS but they aren't sure exactly what they want that feature to look like so it seems to be outside of their current development focus.